# Why does symchk download .exe and .dll files alongside with .pdb

Tags: windows, debugging, symbols

I'm building a local symbol cache of all binaries under my `c:/windows` using `symchk /r c:/windows`

Inspecting the contents of my symbol directory during and after running this command, I find many folders ending with `.exe` and `.dll` which contain actual binaries (in fact, duplicates of those under `c:/windows`) in addition to `.pdb` symbol files proper.

I'd rather avoid wasting disk space with duplicates of files that are already present on my system. Is there any rationale for `symchk` behaving this way, and any options to download `.pdb`s only?

Comment: Microsoft has gone agile, updates come fast and furious.  That's a problem when debugging a minidump created on another machine, odds for a mismatch are large.  So you get the actual binary that was used on that other machine included.  That also means that what you're doing is not productive, you'll clog up the disk space with irrelevant outdated debugging info.

Comment: Too bad there's no option to tell `symchk` that I need symbols only for my local system, but I'd accept your comment as an answer.